Is it linguistic prescriptivism to argue that jargon should be used accurately?
In response to a Meta question questioning their moderation behaviour, a moderator at Skeptics.SE prompted me to post this question here, insisting on the original question that "chemical" has a marketing definition and that it's therefore linguistic prescriptivism to argue it should be used in the scientific sense, even when those definitions are never defined to the consumer and the consumer is likely to conflate the two as is common for non-scientifically educated people.
Obviously whether this is actually linguistic prescriptivism or not would be absolutely immaterial to that meta question, because what the scholars of linguistics shouldn't dictate the content of answers and comments on Skeptics.SE, and this is clearly a pushing of the moderator's own overzealous position, but I'm curious anyway.
I have to admit I don't know much about linguistic prescriptivism or descriptivism, but to me this seems like an overly literal, even fundamentalist interpretation of it. Does the school of linguistic prescriptivism really entail having a compltely laissez faire attitude to jargon being inaccurately "reappropriated" in this way and thereby actively contributing to misinformation?

Generally, prescriptivism prescribes (you should say or write this) whereas descriptivism describes what people say or write. It's more of a grammar and style issue than a linguistics issue. Serious linguists study what people say or write, but don't tell them how to do it. They should be (ahem) non-judgmental about what people say and write if they are studying utterances/discourse from people. Usually, prescriptivism involves some kind of institutional force: a style guide, an official language organization, etc. Many words have specific definitions but people don't always follow those.

IMO, linguistic prescriptivism is about trying to prescribe in linguistics: when discussing the merits of technical jargon in the context of its discipline, it simply isn't linguistics, and I think you'd would be hard pressed to argue against using technical terms the way they are defined in their discipline (I realize the problem here was about the intersection between discipline and general usage; I'd still argue it's not a linguistics issue). Additionally, linguistics also describes presciptivism. It does describe how words are generally perceived in various contexts and registers.

I'd think that linguistic prescriptivism is a layman's term for prescriptivism in language/grammar/usage. I doubt a linguist would use it.

In technical (in this context, science/chemistry) it is reasonable to insist that terminology and jargon be used consistently and accurately. The issue is that in general life and fields like marketing, a term like "chemicals" isn't jargon. In those contexts the word has come to refer specifically to added chemicals, so it would be both prescriptivist and annoyingly pedantic to insist others use it with the sense it has in formal science.

‘Linguistic prescriptivism’ isn’t really a thing to begin with, since prescriptivism is by definition not linguistic – it goes against the very core of linguistics, in fact. It’s sort of akin to ‘scientific religion’ or ‘medical phrenology’.

"Prescriptivism" is often brought up as a sort of boogeyman in pop-linguistics, and it's not hard to see why. The popular perception of linguists is English teachers insisting it's wrong to freely split infinitives, and sentence-final prepositions are something we shouldn't put up with. When someone is first learning what linguistics is, it's important to address that perception.
The problem is, prescriptivism isn't always a bad thing. Foreign language teaching, for example, wouldn't work very well without correcting students' errors. Even if we rule out second-language speakers, language planning is a vital step in reviving an endangered language: some dialect variation has to be sacrificed in pursuit of easier communication. And we can argue whether using the standard dialect should matter for job applications, but like it or not, it does.
Insisting on a particular definition of a word that's commonly used in a different way is, arguably*, prescriptivism. But it's also not necessarily a bad thing. Mathematicians will be very confused if you refer to a set as a "group", even though many people use "group" to mean any collection of elements. When speaking to a dietician, a particular type of rock salt might be "organic", but when speaking to a chemist, it distinctly is not.
However, insisting on that particular definition in general usage is pretty clearly the sort of prescriptivism that pop-linguistics books warn against. Most non-chemists don't use the word "chemical" to refer to any element, compound, or alloy—in fact, in my experience, most chemists don't either (that would be a "substance"). In certain contexts, it can be important to enforce a particular technical definition—I doubt the courts would accept a company insisting that they can use "water" to mean "hydrogen peroxide" in their ingredients list—but in general, non-technical usage, it tends to be a losing battle.
* "Arguably" because you could also say, within that community of practice, it's considered an error to use the common definition.

prescriptivism and grammaticality are two different things. The weather is raining. is not grammatical in English. However, that has nothing to do with prescriptivism. It has to do with idiomaticity. Those are things kids can be taught.

@Lambie Well, that's the thing: how do you define it exactly? It's very hard to come up with a definition of "prescriptivism" that includes "the form you're using is not accepted by the French Academy, stop using it" and doesn't include "the form you're using is deprecated by our language revitalization project, stop using it".

Well, if you go to a law office interview and say something like: I haven't saw him. you might not get the job. So, it's really about whoever is acting as an authority. Leaving out a past participle is dialectal but not "good grammar".  But I don't think linguist/ic + prescriptivism belong in the same collocation.

What is meant clearly is that the clearner in question is not chemically synthesized, but obtained from something natural and/or in a natural way. This is simply tapping in the negative perception of chemical industry.
One can provide many examples of this kind:

Many biologists would rant against the public fear of genetically modified organisms, arguing that all the organisms in the nature are genetically modified, and such a modification occurs all the time in nature - due to mutations and sexual reproduction.
Organic food - obviously, most foods are chemically organic.
Ecological (look up the definition)
Tomato is a fruit (from biology prospective), but would be routinely found in vegetable section of supermarkets, and even referred to as a "vegetable" in ads or cooking books.
Jihad, being a relatively neutral word approximately meaning struggle, has very specific connotation when used in western languages.

And so on, and so on.
